# Graphing a multilevel model in Stata

Tags: plot, stata, interaction, multilevel-analysis

I'm looking for suggestions on how to graph a multilevel model I'm working on.

I'm working with some covariates which I nest around one group: country. Therefore my model looks like this:
Code:

```
melogit trust_d i.soldicontatti##c.individualism c.tightz i.health_d c.difficulties_o c.supportclosec i.vitasociale c.edu_c sex i.diffecon c.agepul c.agepul_q c.familymember || country:
```

I was looking for suggestions on how to possibly graph the interaction effect (i.soldicontatti##c.individualism) by country.
Basically, I would like to show the effects at the different one-order level. I've looked around, but what I have found doesn't help much.
I'm using Stata 16.

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need me to be more specific about my dataset.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1612491-graphing-a-multilevel-model-with-interaction-effect  It's always a good idea to tell people about cross-posting.